# How to proceed with tags with only a single occurence?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

What is the correct way of treating rare tags, say with a single occurence? I just figured out that tags *without* any occurrence are most likely synonyms (which is not obvious from the [tag-overview page](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/tags?page=13&tab=popular)), but that's a different topic.

For some of the tags, it is obvious, that we should search all questions and add the tag (e.g. [big-rip](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/big-rip) or [spitzer-space-telescope](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spitzer-space-telescope)) to the question, since most probably, the tag did not exist yet when some questions have been asked.

But what about the other tags (like [anomaly](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anomaly), [time-domain-astronomy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/time-domain-astronomy), and many more, see screenshot) with a single occurrence? Should we discuss every single one of them?

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Don't worry about them too much. Tags which are only used once and have no tag wiki are [automatically deleted after six months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127700/295232). There's a small risk the question may end up [untagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167879/295232) but only if it has no other tags, which is usually not the case.

Comment: Aha! I wonder if that's what happened here [How did my question become untagged?](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1089/12102)

Comment: @uhoh very likely. That happened 6.5 months after asking the question. I don't know for sure, and the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/26731/*) doesn't contain copies of the question from 2018.

Comment: Oh, that seems too close to be a coincidence. Thanks, mystery solved! Feel free to post a speculative answer there for me to accept.